# how to add items to a single column table in sqlite3

Tags: sql, python-3.x, database, sqlite

I am new to databases. I am trying to create a sqlite database with a table containing single column.

Once created, I want to add items to that column in a for loop. However when I do that it only adds the first item and nothing else.

What am I doing wrong?

See below for the code:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> con = sqlite3.connect('posts.db')
>>> cur = con.cursor()
>>> cur.execute('CREATE TABLE posts(ID TEXT)')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f2b03733650>

>>> con.commit()

>>> for i in 'hello':
...     cur.execute('INSERT INTO posts VALUES(?)',(i,))
...     con.commit()
...     cur.execute('SELECT * FROM posts')
...     print(cur.fetchone())
...
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f2b03733650>
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f2b03733650>
('h',)
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f2b03733650>
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f2b03733650>
('h',)
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f2b03733650>
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f2b03733650>
('h',)
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f2b03733650>
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f2b03733650>
('h',)
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f2b03733650>
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f2b03733650>
('h',)
```

As you can see above it just seems to contain the `h` character and not the rest of the characters in `hello`

Comment: To me it looks like you execute a new select query for each iteration in the `for` loop and always print the first returned row for that query. Try to separate the `for` loop and the select cursor loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would break it up in 2 iterations

```
for i in 'hello':
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO posts VALUES(?)',(i,))

con.commit()

for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM posts'):
    print row
```